# I am encountering issues when transferring USDC tokens

Tags: tokens, polygon, transfer

When I transfer USDC tokens on the Polygon mainnet at https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com, I encounter an error stating that the 'transfer' method is not found. Upon checking the list of methods for the contract, I observe that it does not include the 'transfer' method. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Copy the ABI from the implementation here https://polygonscan.com/address/0xdd9185db084f5c4fff3b4f70e7ba62123b812226#code

Comment: How can I retrieve the ABI without having to search on polygonscan.com? I tried using the Polygon API, but it doesn't provide sufficient methods for that

Comment: You have to know the source code of the contract. So either you get it from github or from polygonscan.